# Recommended touch-compatible Wacom Device

Tags: touchpad, hardware, compatibility, wacom

I need to use a touch "mouse" on my desktop PC, which works with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Theoretically, a Wacom Tablet should be Linux compatible, but there are blog posts which indicate that plenty of people suffers from installation problems.

My question is: Are there any Wacom **TOUCH** devices that *really* plug and play? Without editing Xorg configuration and stuff like that?

I would like an "easy" installation.

Please specify:

- Wacom device model.
- Ubuntu (or other Linux) Version.
- procedure followed for installation.

Comment: I've tryed with Wacom Bamboo Pad USB (IT DOES NOT WORK) (http://www.wacom.com/en/us/everyday/bamboo-pad-usb) ON:
UBUNTU 12.04 LTS (kernel linux 3.2.x) and Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 wheezy (Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae i686).
Followed the LinuxWacom Project instruction on SourceForge: Install input-wacom, Install xf86-input-wacom and ReInstall libwacom.
I have NOT TRIED to edit the configuration of the X Server.

Comment: The content of your comment should be added to your actual question.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 has plug and play support for Wacom CTL 472.